# How do I make the UI in IE 8 update as lines of JavaScript are executed in a function, rather than at the end of of the function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to display a progress bar while ajax calls populate a form. I have a function called LOADFORM(). It launches a jquery dialog box, displays a progress bar, calles a few other non-async ajax calls to get data. With each data call complete it advances the progress bar and at the end it hides the progressbar and displays the form. This works perfecly in Firfox, but in IE, it just shows the completed form. I doesn't update the UI until the function is done running and by that time everything is complete, but the user has to sit at a uneventful screen for several seconds. How do I make the UI in IE 8 update as lines of JavaScript are executed in a function?

Example:

```
ActionReportForms.prototype.LoadFormData = function (constId, formType) {
    //HOOK UP DATE PICKER
    $('#' + this.TPLDATEFIELD_ID).datepicker();
    $('#' + this.CRDATEFIELD_ID).datepicker();

    //CLEAR FIELDS
    this.ClearFormFields();

    //HIDE ERRORS
    this.ShowError(false, "");

    //SHOW PROGRESS BAR
    this.ShowProgress(true, 30, "loading...");

    this.ShowDialogBox();

    //POPULATE FIELDS
    this.GetAccountName(constId);
    this.ShowProgress(true, 60, "loading...proposals");
    this.GetProposlas(constId);
    this.ShowProgress(true, 90, "loading...action types");
    this.GetActionTypes();
    this.ShowProgress(true, 100, "loading...complete");
    this.ConstituentID = constId;
    $("#" + this.CONSTITUENTID_ID + ":input").val("");
    $("#" + this.CONSTITUENTID_ID + ":input").val(constId);





    //HIDE
    $('#' + this.TPLDATEFIELD_ID).datepicker("hide");
    $('#' + this.CRDATEFIELD_ID).datepicker("hide");

    //TOGGLE FORM
    if (formType != "") {
        ToggleForms(formType);
    }

    //HIDE PROGRESS BAR
    this.ShowProgress(false, 0, "");

}
```

Thanks,
T

Comment: Might have to do with the way IE draws the page. AFAIK, all modern browsers except IE parse and draw the elements as the page loads. IE waits until the whole (or most of the) page is loaded to parse and draw. IE has to be tweaked in the registry to kind of act that way. Might be the same issue here.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm calling this function from a button. The button passes in an id, that configures the form for that id.

Answer (score 0):

You could chain the different stages together with window.setTimout(). This gives the browser a little time to redraw the page. In this example I set the timeout to 1ms. I am not shure if that will do the trick. Note that I start the chain at the end of the outer function.

```
ActionReportForms.prototype.LoadFormData = function (constId, formType) {
    //HOOK UP DATE PICKER
    $('#' + this.TPLDATEFIELD_ID).datepicker();
    $('#' + this.CRDATEFIELD_ID).datepicker();

    //CLEAR FIELDS
    this.ClearFormFields();

    //HIDE ERRORS
    var hideErrors = function()
    {
        this.ShowError(false, "");
        window.setTimeout(showProgessBar, 1);
    };

    //SHOW PROGRESS BAR
    var showProgressBar = function()
    {
        this.ShowProgress(true, 30, "loading...");
        this.ShowDialogBox();
        window.setTimeout(populateFields, 1);
    };

    //POPULATE FIELDS
    var populateFields = function()
    {
        this.GetAccountName(constId);
        this.ShowProgress(true, 60, "loading...proposals");
        window.setTimeout(loadProposals, 1);
    };

    var loadProposals = function()
    {
        this.GetProposlas(constId);
        this.ShowProgress(true, 90, "loading...action types");
        window.setTimeout(loadActionTypes, 1);
    };

    var loadActionTypes = function()
    {
        this.GetActionTypes();
        this.ShowProgress(true, 100, "loading...complete");
        this.ConstituentID = constId;
        $("#" + this.CONSTITUENTID_ID + ":input").val("");
        $("#" + this.CONSTITUENTID_ID + ":input").val(constId);

        //HIDE
        $('#' + this.TPLDATEFIELD_ID).datepicker("hide");
        $('#' + this.CRDATEFIELD_ID).datepicker("hide");

        //TOGGLE FORM
        if (formType != "") {
            ToggleForms(formType);
        }

        //HIDE PROGRESS BAR
        this.ShowProgress(false, 0, "");
    };

    // Start with hide errors.
    hideErrors();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work. The GetProposlas() method actually takes a second or two. Its not a matter of time. The function runs, executes each line, then updates the UI with the chnages. Instead of executing each line and updating the UI after each line. Again, it works perfectly in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Chaining via callbacks. Its all about the callbacks. I've been avoiding them because they're ugly and hard to read, but they allow you update the DOM while the rest of your code runs, IN IE. This is un

```
function LoadFormCall(constId, formType) {
    //HOOK UP DATE PICKER
    $('#' + this.TPLDATEFIELD_ID).datepicker();
    $('#' + this.CRDATEFIELD_ID).datepicker();
    arfObj.hiddenStuff1 = constId;
    arfObj.hiddenStuff2 = formType;
    //CLEAR FIELDS
    arfObj.ClearFormFields();

    //HIDE ERRORS
    arfObj.ShowError(false, "");

    //SHOW PROGRESS BAR
    arfObj.ShowProgress(true, 30, "loading...");

    //OPEN DIALOG
    ShowDialogBox();

    //POPULATE FIELDS
    //THIS CALLS A JQUERY $.ajax call with a callback execute in the success function
    //AND SO BEGINS THE CHAIN.
    arfObj.GetAccountName1(constId, LoadFormCall2); 
};

function LoadFormCall2() {
    constId = arfObj.hiddenStuff1;
    arfObj.ShowProgress(true, 60, "loading...proposals");
    arfObj.GetProposals1(constId, LoadFormCall3);
};

function LoadFormCall3() {
    arfObj.ShowProgress(true, 90, "loading...action types");
    arfObj.GetActionTypes1(LoadFormCall4);
}

function LoadFormCall4(){
    arfObj.ShowProgress(true, 100, "loading...complete");
    arfObj.ConstituentID = constId;


    $("#" + arfObj.CONSTITUENTID_ID + ":input").val("");
    $("#" + arfObj.CONSTITUENTID_ID + ":input").val(constId);

    //HIDE
    $('#' + arfObj.TPLDATEFIELD_ID).datepicker("hide");
    $('#' + arfObj.CRDATEFIELD_ID).datepicker("hide");

    //TOGGLE FORM
    if (arfObj.hiddenStuff2 != "") {
        ToggleForms(arfObj.hiddenStuff2);
    }

    //HIDE PROGRESS BAR
    arfObj.ShowProgress(false, 0, "");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, async programming is a bit harder, but it pays off in the user experience. In your case, making it async will cause a browser refresh at the end of every XHR, whereas making the XHRs async will keep the UI locked waiting for the XHRs to end. Bad idea, always make slow things async

Answer (score 0):

This only appears to work in Firefox because it fakes synchronous XMLHttpRequest using asynchronous XMLHttpRequest. And while it's waiting for the request to complete, it updates the screen, because it hasn't got anything better to do.

But really, you should stop using synchronous XMLHttpRequest.